# How to insert data from table1 to table2 if they got something in common?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got 2 tables in same database in MYSQL and I want insert the columnA in table1 to columnA in table2 and my condition is if table1.name is equal to table2.name. I tried this but didnt work

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (solId, openTime, closingTime, guid)  
SELECT solId, openTime, closingTime, guid
FROM Table1
WHERE Table2.name = Table1.name;
```

Comment: That where makes no sense. You dont have access to table2 data there. Anyways, what are you trying to achieve? insert all the data or just some?

Comment: some data only  where tabel 1 and table 2 have same value in column id

Comment: Then you already have data on table2? Just join with that table on the select on that field. You can select first and when that gives you want you need to insert then just insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want an `update`:

```
update table2 t2 join
       table1 t1
       on t1.name = t2.name
    set t2.solId = t1.solId,
        t2.openTime = t1.openTime,
        t2.closingTime = t1.closingTime,
        t2.guid = t1.guid;
```